# Comparison of running times

Tags: algorithm, math, logging, computer-science

I am studying algorithms on my own. I use [Introduction to Algorithms (CLRS)](https://www.google.de/search?q=Introduction+to+Algorithms) and find it fun. Trying to solve its problems, I faced some difficulties in this question (Comparison of running times).
I know the rules and I found the answer but I need someone to explain it to me in detail. As you can see below the answer of log n running time.
I tried to log the number in my calculator but it does not match the one below. For example, when I used log(2^1000000) in my calculator, it gives me a whole new answer not this one 9.9e301029.

I would appreciate any help you provide

lg n = T µs => n = 2^T µs

```
lg n = 1 second  => n = 2^1000000 = 9.9e301029
lg n = 1 minute  => n = 2^60000000 = 5.5e18061799
lg n = 1 hour    => n = 2^3600000000
lg n = 1 day     => n = 2^86400000000
lg n = 1 month   => n = 2^2592000000000
lg n = 1 year    => n = 2^31536000000000
lg n = 1 century => n = 2^3153600000000000
```

Answer (score 0):

Binary search might have a runtime of log2 (n) µs (the constant factor is probably a lot smaller). Binary search is fast. If you have a powerful computer you might fit an array of 64 billion bytes into memory, and binary search will take 36 microseconds. Yes, you couldn't build computer memory big enough to hold an array where binary search takes a millisecond using all the silicone in the universe.

Answer (score 0):

`2^1000000 = 9.9e301029`

`log(2^1000000) = 1000000` (assuming base 2)

`1000000µs = 1s`

Clear now?

Most calculators default to log base 10, so you need to convert to log base 2 using the following formula:

`log_b(x) = log_a(x) / log_a(b)`